# How much memory is free?

Tags: memory-usage

How much memory is free? From my understanding i have 1GB of memory, and it says free is 71MB?

But why does it say that i have 536 free in buffers? So am I really using all my ram or not?

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           994        923         71          0        111        352
-/+ buffers/cache:        458        536
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Total memory is 1GB , 923 Megabyte used, 71 Megabyte free Now , yes your memory is fully Used, Buffer is Reading your files that mean accessing your Drive to read the files, To Find more which process consuming more Memory use. to know more about memory usage use the command in following link to know more

[TOP Commands](http://www.linuxmental.com/top-commands-powerful-monitoring-tool-linux)

Comment: Here is a screenshot of my top. http://i.imgur.com/VcmKrCN.jpg

Im guessing its mysql?

Comment: Yes every database such as mysql will use lot of memory

Comment: But this doesnt seam normal does it? What can i check to make sure it doesnt? Or do i get more ram?

Comment: I had the same setup before and it never used this much

Comment: Other application are running which will use mysql ?, Sure there is something running which one is using mysql, so what its consuming

Comment: Im running a zabbix server which collects snmp data and writes it. But it seems to be taking too much ram.

Comment: If so the Consuming ram is normal, we have a wordpress site with 1GB RAM its using 60% RAM.. Zabbix use lot more than Wp

Comment: weird it used to use only 50% okay thank you!